# Por que o ng-repeat do AngularJS não funciona no Modal do Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap, modal, ng-repeat

Em meu projeto, eu utilizei um aninhamento de `ng-repeat` para montar vários `checkbox` dinamicamente, possibilitando o usuário combinar **filtros**, o que **funciona** perfeitamente quando meu *controller* carrega as listas.

Agora, o usuário pediu para colocar esses filtros dentro de um `modal`, mas aparentemente o `ng-repeat` não funciona dentro do modal. Por que isso acontece?

Não estou pedindo soluções alternativas como utilizar o `ui.bootstrap` e injetar o `modal` do próprio angular. Eu quero de fato saber o motivo pelo qual não funciona com o modal nativamente.

O `javascript` do Bootstrap elimina as tags contendo o `ng-repeat` ou algo do tipo? Estou utilizando da forma errada?

Aqui um exemplo do meu `HTML`:

```
        <!-- SEPARATED MODAL BODY - WORKS -->
        <div ng-repeat="campo in camposFiltradosMotorista">
            <div ng-repeat="tipo in tiposMotorista[campo]" class="checkbox checkbox-primary" class="styled">
                <strong>
                    <input id="motorista{{tipo}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="tiposMotoristaSelecionados[campo][tipo]" />
                    <label for="motorista{{tipo}}">
                        {{tipo}} - ({{ (motoristasFiltrados | filter:count(campo, tipo)).length }})
                    </label>
                </strong>
            </div>
            <hr ng-if="!$last" />
        </div>

        <div class="modal inmodal" id="filtro-modal-motoristas" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <i class="fa fa-laptop modal-icon"></i>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Filtros de Motorista</h4>
                        <small class="font-bold"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i> Você pode combinar vários filtros</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <span>Filtros</span>
                        <!-- INSIDE MODAL BODY - DOESN'T WORK :( -->
                        <div ng-repeat="campo in camposFiltradosMotorista">
                            <div ng-repeat="tipo in tiposMotorista[campo]" class="checkbox checkbox-primary" class="styled">
                                <strong>
                                    <input id="motorista{{tipo}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="tiposMotoristaSelecionados[campo][tipo]" />
                                    <label for="motorista{{tipo}}">
                                        {{tipo}} - ({{ (motoristasFiltrados | filter:count(campo, tipo)).length }})
                                    </label>
                                </strong>
                            </div>
                            <hr ng-if="!$last" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: No Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+I (Ferramentas do desenvolvedor): veja em Console se há algum erro, se sim, poste aqui, por favor.

Comment: Minha aposta cega: sua interface modal está abrindo com escopo isolado, e consequentemente ignorando `camposFiltradosMotorista` (já que este pertence a um escopo antecessor.)

Comment: @NotTheRealHemingway já verifiquei, não tem qualquer erro.

Comment: @OnoSendai até que faz sentido. O que poderia fazer com que fosse um escopo isolado? Na verdade eu já tentei utilizar o modal do `ui.bootstrap` do angular, mas não sei como fazer ele carregar esse `modal-body`. Nos exemplos que vi, tem que usar um `resolve` que não entendi como usar e passar todos esses `models` que eu uso no `html`.

Comment: pode postar o seu javascript também?

Answer (score 1):

Você não mencionou qual mecanismo de modal você está usando - supondo que você criou o seu próprio, verifique a sua definição de escopo:

```
app.directive('modalDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {}        // Cria uma versão isolada do escopo
  }
}
```

Caso deseje ter acesso a propriedades definidas em escopos de elementos que encapsulam a diretiva, utilize `true` na definição:

```
app.directive('modalDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true      // Herda escopo
  }
}
```